# OpenLayers SLD duplication problem

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, sld

Hey guys i am creating a web map and I am running into a little problem. I am serving two WMS layers from GeoServer to my OpenLayers script. For styling I am using SLD in GeoServer. The SLD script works fine in LayersPreview in GeoServer but on my Openlayers map when I zoom all the way in, my labels for my polygon double. I have read one or two issues with this and some have suggested using Meta-Tiling. My problem come in when trying to implement this option. No errors pop up but my results are the same. Below is my OpenLayers Code, am I doing something wrong or is there a error in my code?

```
        function init() {

        map = new OpenLayers.Map('map',{
            controls:[
                new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher()
            ],
            maxExtent:new OpenLayers.Bounds(
                -128*156543.0339,
                -128*156543.0339,
                128*156543.0339,
                128*156543.0339),
            resolution:611.496,
            units:'m',
            projection:new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:900913'),
            displayProjection:new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),

        });
        //Base Layers 
    arrayOSM = [

             "http://otile1.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/osm/${z}/${x}/${y}.jpg",

             "http://otile2.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/osm/${z}/${x}/${y}.jpg",

             "http://otile3.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/osm/${z}/${x}/${y}.jpg",

             "http://otile4.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/osm/${z}/${x}/${y}.jpg"
   ];
   arrayAerial = [

             "http://oatile1.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/sat/${z}/${x}/${y}.jpg",

             "http://oatile2.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/sat/${z}/${x}/${y}.jpg",

             "http://oatile3.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/sat/${z}/${x}/${y}.jpg",

             "http://oatile4.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/sat/${z}/${x}/${y}.jpg"
   ];
   baseOSM = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("MapQuest-OSM Tiles", arrayOSM);
   baseAerial = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("MapQuest Open Aerial Tiles",arrayAerial);

   //Adding the 1st layer 
  Calv_Intersects = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Calvert Intersections",

      "http://vmhvsandbox.soon.curg.com:8080/geoserver/WinPS/wms?",
    {
      layers:'WorkingAPS:Calv_Intersections',
      transparent:true,
      format:'image/png'
    },

    {
      isBaseLayer:false,
      opacity:7 
    }

      );
    // Adding the second layer 
    Calv_Quads = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Calvert Quads",            
            "http://vmhvsandbox.soon.ceng.com:8080/geoserver/WoPS/wms?",
    {
     layers:'WorkingAPS:Calv_Quads',
     transparent:true,
             format:'image/png',
     tiled:true,        
     tilesOrgin:[map.maxExtent.left,map.maxExtent.bottom]
    },
    {
      isBaseLayer:false,
      opacity:45  
        }

      );
    //Adding all layers
    map.addLayer(baseOSM);
    map.addLayer(baseAerial);
    map.addLayers([Calv_Intersects,Calv_Quads]);
    //Setting zoom levels on both layers
    map.events.on({ "zoomend": function (e) {
       if (this.getZoom() > 16) {
        Calv_Intersects.setVisibility(false);
            Calv_Quads.setVisibility(true);
       }
       else {
              Calv_Quads.setVisibility(false);
          Calv_Intersects.setVisibility(true);
          }
     }
    });
   //Adding a pop up window 
    info = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
        url:'http://vmhvsandbox.soon.ceng.com:8080/geoserver/WPS/wms?', 
    title: 'Identify features by clicking',
    queryVisible: true,
    eventListeners: {
        getfeatureinfo: function(event) {
        map.addPopup(new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
            "c",
            map.getLonLatFromPixel(event.xy),
        null,
        event.text,
        null,
        true
          ));
         }
        }
      });
    //Map Controls
      map.addControl(info);
      info.activate();
      map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
      map.setCenter(
      new OpenLayers.LonLat(-76.631,39.083).transform(
      new  OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),map.getProjectionObject()), 8
          );       
      }
```

Comment: Minor nit, but highly relevant... You've misspelled "tileOrigin" when you pass it to the second layer's constructor, and this parameter is required for meta-tiling.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you can check on grouping label:

1. http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-reference/labeling.html#grouping-features-group
2. http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-reference/labeling.html#labelallgroup

Hopes that will help you.

Regards,
Nas

Comment: Unfortunately    I am still getting duplicate Labels. In layer preview on GeoServer,If I Switch the Tiling: option to Tiled, I can reproduce the Error. So I know I need to serve my WMS Layer as a single Tile I am just either confused on how to do that or why Meta-Tiling is not working...

Comment: here an example from OpenLayers: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/single-tile.html

Comment: Thank you Nasrulhazim  for  your help. I found a solution  for anyone that is having this problem as well. Instead of meta tiling call I used {singleTile:true, ratio:1}